# Save an object key that is inside array

Tags: angular, typescript

So i don't have any code to show you. I want to save an object key(id) that is inside of an array. When i click in one of the `ngFor` items saves it(id) in a variable. if i click in another item compare the variable that contains the previous id with the actual item id that i selected. Can you guys help me?

```
async trocarMercado(mercado) {
  this.mercado = mercado;

  console.log(this.mercado);

  if (this.mercadoAnterior != this.mercado.id) {
    this.mercadoAnterior = this.mercado.id;
  }
  console.log(this.mercadoAnterior)

  if (this.carrinho.length > 1) {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Atenção',
      message: 'Se entrar num novo mercado vai perder o carrinho do mercado anterior. Tem a certeza?',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Sim',
        handler: () => {
          this.carrinho.length = 0;
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['/produtos']);
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Não',
        handler: () => {

        }
      }]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }

}
```

Comment: where is your `*ngFor` and `click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing it in `clickedItem` and assuming you have `*ngFor` as shown below`:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" ><a class="dropdown-item btn-sm" (click)="eventClick(item)" >{{ item.title }}</a></li>
```

Now in your component:

```
eventClick(item: any) {

 if(item === this.clickedItem) {

   console.log('same item clicked nothing to do here');
   } else  {
   this.clickedItem = item;
   console.log('different item clicked , store it now');
  }

}
```

Comment: i understood what you give me but the first time i select a item it is always diferent from this.clickedId because clickedId is empty. What can i do to make that the first time i select an item it will do nothing?

Comment: You need to set the value of `clickedItem` on load/ `onInit` in your component calss

Answer (score 0):

It's solved for anyone who have a similar problem .

```js
if(mercado.id == this.clickedId || this.clickedId == undefined){
    this.mercadoVer=true;
    this.clickedId= mercado.id;
    const loading = await this.loadCtrl.create({
      message: 'Aguarde...',
      duration: 500
    });
    await loading.present();
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['/produtos'])
  }else{
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Atenção',
      message: 'Se entrar num novo mercado vai perder o carrinho do mercado anterior. Tem a certeza?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Sim',
          handler: async () => {
          this.carrinho.length= 0;
          this.clickedId= mercado.id;
          const loading = await this.loadCtrl.create({
            message: 'Aguarde...',
            duration: 500
          });
            await loading.present();
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['/produtos']);
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Não',
          handler: () => {
          
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
```